# Different ways to store information efficiently when working with limited space

Tags: c, pebble-watch, pebble-sdk

I am and have been working on software for the Pebble. It is the first time I have worked with **C**, and I am struggling to get my head around how to manage information/data within the program.
I am used to being able to have multi-dimensional arrays with thousands of entries. With the Pebble we are very limited.

I can talk to the requirements for my program, but happy to see any sort of discussion on the topic.

The application I am building needs to store a running feed of data with every button press. Ideally I would like to store one binary value and two small integer values with each press. I would like to take advantage of the local storage on the Pebble which is limited to 256 bytes per array which presents a challenge.

I have thought about using a custom struct - and having multiple arrays of those, making sure to check that each array doesn't exceed the 256 byte mark. It just seems really messy and complicated to manage... am I missing something fundamentally simple, or does it need to be this complicated?

At the moment my program only stores the binary value and I haven't bothered with the small integer values at all.

Comment: What is the range of the small integers you wish to store? For example, 0-65535, 0-255, smaller?

Comment: The tighter you want to pack your data, the more messy and complicated it will be. That's the trade-off between space and complexity/time in data representation. The simplest very tight packing scheme would be to use a minimal number of bits for each type of data item. For example, if a data item can take on 3 values, you only need two bits. And if you have another value that only needs 5 bits, you can pack both of these into one byte. It's possible to get tighter than that but it gets messier then, too. :)

Comment: If array size is limited, you can use a linked list of structs containing each one a 256 bytes array and a pointer to the next struct.

Comment: @MahonriMoriancumer - I would need to use 0-65535, 255 isn't enough. It is basically going to be used as an offset for the time.

Comment: @doukremt - That sounds like what I was thinking of doing. Are there any simple examples you could link me to so I can better understand how it works?

Comment: @strat, 0-65535 will require two bytes (16 bits).  So, for two such  integer values, four bytes are required.  Plus the extra bit (ie:binary value).  If you can reduce at least one of the ranges to 0-32767, you could neatly pack all three values into four bytes.  Is the 0-32767 range suitable for one of the small integer values?

Comment: @MahonriMoriancumer so how do I go about chaining this all together? I need to make sure I keep the order of this all correct. I guess I would need to have room for a pointer at the end of the 256 bytes to point to the next array?

Comment: Is this for persistent storage? That is the only storage that I believe has the 256 byte limit. In that case the data is accessed by a 32 bit key which would act as the pointer to the block.

Comment: @BradBudlong Yes, the persistent storage on the watch. Basically I want to store every piece of data into storage so that if the user quits - they can re-open and not have lost any data.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you could define structures as follows:

```
#pragma pack(1)
typedef struct STREAM_RECORD_S
   {
   unsigned short uint16;        // The uint16 field will store a number from 0-65535
   unsigned short uint15 : 15;   // The uint15 field will store a number from 0-32767
   unsigned short binary : 1;    // The binary field will store a number from 0-1
   } STREAM_RECORD_T;

typedef struct STREAM_BLOCK_S
   {
   struct STREAM_BLOCK_S *nextBlock;  // Store a pointer to the next block.
   STREAM_RECORD_T        records[1]; // Array of records for this block. 
   } STREAM_BLOCK_T;
#pragma pack(0);
```

The actual number of records in the array would depend on the size of the nextBlock pointer.  For example, if you are running with 32-bit addressing, the nextBlock size would likely be 4 bytes; and it would be 2 bytes with 16-bit addressing, or 8 bytes with 64-bit addressing. (I do not know the pointer size on an ARM Cortex-M3 processor).

So, recordsPerArray = (256 - sizeof(nextBlock)) / sizeof(STREAM_RECORD_T);

Comment: Thanks for this, I am going to try to understand what is happening here. I am quite new to C, pointers are what cause me most grief when getting my head around this stuff.